# How to make a tab active when clicked by using pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, modifier

I am working on the below nav bar

```
<nav class="nav" >
        <ul class="nav__list">
            <li id="authors-tag" class="nav__list__item"><a class="nav__list__item__link" href="#">Authors</a></li>
            <li id="publishers-tag" class="nav__list__item"><a class="nav__list__item__link" href="#">Publishers</a></li>
            <li id="books-tag" class="nav__list__item"><a class="nav__list__item__link" href="#">Books</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

By using pure JS, I am trying to add an event listener to each tab of the nav bar, so that when the user clicks on a li item, the tab will be made active by adding a modifier class to that DOM element to highlight it.

So far every answer I've found is using jQuery.

Below's my main.js

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__list__item__link');
tabs.forEach(clickedTab =>{
  clickedTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    tabs.forEach( tab => {
      tab.classList.remove('active');
    });
    e.target.classList.add('.active');
  });
});
```

I've also tried using getAttribute by id but I just can't seem to nail it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drop the point before `active` in `.classList.add()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `.` from `e.target.classList.add('.active');`, e.g. `e.target.classList.add('active');`.

```
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__list__item__link');
tabs.forEach(clickedTab =>{
  clickedTab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    tabs.forEach( tab => {
      tab.classList.remove('active');
    });
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: It's nice if you can explain why removing the dot will fix the issue.

Comment: It does not need a dot in `classList.add` and `classList.remove`.

Comment: While this is a correct answer, SO discourages typo questions (they cannot be searched, and don't have any value for anyone other than the OP). For that reason, in the future, you shouldn't answer them; leave a comment and flag the question for closure instead.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot solve my case for this part. it didn't change when another tab was active.

```js
function openTab(tabName) {
    var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
        tab.classList.remove('active');
    });

    var tabContents = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
    tabContents.forEach(function (content) {
        content.style.display = 'none';
    });

    var selectedTab = document.getElementById(tabName);
    if (selectedTab) {
        selectedTab.style.display = 'block';
        selectedTab.classList.add('active');
    }
}
```

```css
.custom-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 2 0 140px;
  width: 300px; /* Set the desired width */
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 6px 0.9vw;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color : #444444;
  font-family: 'roboto';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.tab.active {
  background-color: #444444;
  color : white;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 62px;
}

@media only screen and  and (max-width: 1064px){

}
```

```html
<div class="custom-tabs">
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab active" onclick="openTab('tab1')">JAKARTA</div>
        <div class="tab" onclick="openTab('tab2')">BANDUNG</div>
        <div class="tab" onclick="openTab('tab3')">SURABAYA</div>
        <div class="tab" onclick="openTab('tab4')">BALI</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab Content for Tab 1 -->
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content" style="display: block;">
        [INSERT_ELEMENTOR id="82349"]
    </div>

    <!-- Tab Content for Tab 2 -->
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
        [INSERT_ELEMENTOR id="82404"]
    </div>

    <!-- Tab Content for Tab 3 -->
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
        [INSERT_ELEMENTOR id="82410"]
    </div>
    <!-- Tab Content for Tab 4 -->
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-content">
        [INSERT_ELEMENTOR id="82416"]
    </div>
</div>
```

Help me to fix the problem